# Cannot compile to a seperate directory using make

Tags: gcc, directory, makefile

I am trying to compile to a binaries directory... everything works if I compile to the root directly. At first, I attempted to let gcc handle it by passing bin/ under the -o flag. Make appears (infuriatingly) to just remove the path from the target and compile to the root anyway...

Then I tried letting make itself handle it, however it now fails to find the rule to compile anything.

The other thing I tried is adding:

```
$(OBJECTS):
```

to the first rule, but then make just calls gcc by itself with no arguments.

This is the version where I let make handle the paths:

```
CC = gcc
DIR = bin
TARGETS = cloud controller
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(DIR)/, $(TARGETS))

all: $(OBJECTS)

$(DIR)/%: $@.c
        $(CC) $< -o $@

$(DIR):
        mkdir $(DIR)
```

This is the version where I let gcc handle the paths:

```
CC = gcc
DIR = bin
TARGETS = cloud controller

all: $(TARGETS)
    mkdir $(DIR) -p

%: $@.c
        $(CC) $< -o $(DIR)/$@
```

Comment: You cannot use `$@` in the prerequisite like that. That's the main part of your problem. And no, `gcc` wasn't ignoring the directory in the second attempt. make was ignoring your rule entirely (try removing it from the Makefile entirely to see what I mean). Use `%` in the prerequisite to match the `%` in the target.

Comment: Yay! Thank you thank you thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `$@` to `%`, as per @[EtanReisner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870287/cannot-compile-to-a-seperate-directory-using-make#comment53572391_32870287)'s comment.